# “dd” command copy “.img” file to SD card and remain a free space

Tags: dd

I have the 16GB SD card and the 1.5GB *.img* file.

This *.img* file consist of 2 partition:

- boot: 2MB
- sys: ~1.5GB

I copy *.img* to SD card with this command:

```
dd if=*.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

After above command,
partitions and files has been created in my SD card.

But **free space** has a problem:

the partition in the SD card after `dd`

- boot: used 2MB, free space remain
- sys: used 1.5GB , free space remain ~0MB.
- Non-used free space ~14GB

I hope *Not-used free space ~14GB* integrated into sys partition.

How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

gparted would do that, f you don't mind using a GUI or installing a tool if don't have it yet. I recommend it, powerful and useful.